# I can't use input file in my project because Clion seems to not see the file

Tags: c

I recently started using Clion to program in c, but it seems that Clion can't open a txt file for input in my project. I read online that i have to set a proper working directory so that the IDE can see the input file, but every time i tried to change the working directory, nothing changed. I created a simple program to test if the txt file is opened correctly:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  if((fp = fopen("file.txt", "r")) == NULL)

      {
          printf("Error: file.txt is not present\n");
          exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }
   return 0;
}
```

The program always print the error. I placed the txt in the main folder of this project, which contains:

1. .idea                (folder)
2. cmake-build-debug    (folder)
3. CmakeLists.txt       (file)
4. main.c               (file)
5. file.txt             (the txt file that i want to be open in my program)

I think i have to place file.txt inside the folder that contains the .exe file (cmake-build-debug) but also in this case the output of the program is the same.

Comment: check [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dTtZEAfh_LM)

Comment: Specify an absolute path to `fopen`.

Comment: Unfortunately i already saw that video and it didn't help.

Comment: I tried specifing the path and now it works correctly, thank you .

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current directory using getcwd to find where the program is looking for file.txt

```
char cwd[PATH_MAX];
if (getcwd(cwd, sizeof(cwd)) != NULL) {
    printf("Current working dir: %s\n", cwd);
}
```

Comment: it says that the current working directory is the main folder i was talking about in the question, where the file.txt is already located.